# Same hash of PHP object in Python

Tags: php, python, hash, compatibility

I have a little problem:
On one hand I have a parser, which takes a string, wraps it into a PHP object and returns a hashed string of this object.
On the other hand a new version of parser is written on Python and new parser take a string, hash it and return also as a string.

And there I have a compability issue. **The same string** hashed as PHP object and hashed as string returns **a different result**. Is there a way to get PHP object in python, to obtain exact same result as in PHP-parser?
Here a bites of code:

PHP:

```
function num_converter() {
    $string_1 = '1234';
    $string_2 = '567890';

    $hash = String_to_hash::stringHash((object)array(
                        'number'=>$string_1.' '.$string_2,
                        'number2'=>$number3,
                ));
    return array_push($Reply, $hash);
}
```

And here is same functionality code in Python:

```
def num_converter():
    string_1 = '1234'
    string_2 = '567890'
    number3 = digits # type of int

    string_to_hash = string_1 + " " + string_2 + str(number3)
    return hashlib.md5(string_to_hash.encode()).hexdigest().upper()
```

Comment: Can you share some example output, such one can see the difference?

Comment: `String_to_hash` is not a PHP builtin, consequently we can't tell what it outputs or not. Similarly, `self.get_raw` is defined elsewhere. Please make sure that code you post is a [minimal, self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org/) that we can actually run and experiment with.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to use the same hash algorithm. For example:

**PHP**

```
php > echo hash('sha512', 'foo');
```

Result: `f7fbba6e0636f890e56fbbf3283e524c6fa3204ae298382d624741d0dc6638326e282c41be5e4254d8820772c5518a2c5a8c0c7f7eda19594a7eb539453e1ed7`

**Python**

```
import hashlib
hashlib.sha512(b'foo').hexdigest()
```

Result: `'f7fbba6e0636f890e56fbbf3283e524c6fa3204ae298382d624741d0dc6638326e282c41be5e4254d8820772c5518a2c5a8c0c7f7eda19594a7eb539453e1ed7'`